# Security Conferences in United Kingdom

Tags: professional-education, conference

I have already read the post of [best security conferences](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/best-security-conferences), but am not able to find any **academic** security conferences, even through [Microsoft Academic Search](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=2&last=5&start=1&end=100).

I admit this question is quite localized, but still hope to find an answer. Any list, source (of both security specific and general computing) will be greatly appreciated. In addition please describe how you learned about this conference or list

I will be collecting the answers in a unified [Google Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AtTFBGAsNW9jdGR2ZmpERHVuTF9Gc3ZvYkQ5NXBncnc&hl=zh_CN&authkey=COHPi7AH) for community use.

Comment: Changed to community wiki

Comment: Are you looking for conferences that do peer review and publish proceedings?  Or just a generally academic focus?

Comment: What are you looking for?  Are you really looking for an academic conference in any aspect of computer security whatsoever, as long as it is in the UK?  I'm not sure that's going to make sense, but if that's what you want, we can try to help.

Comment: @nealmcb, the former.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, that is what I want....

Comment: @Dante - almost all the conferences I am aware of, I find out about through my memberships of bodies or through my network of contacts.

Answer (score 3):

[SECURECOMM 2011](http://www.securecomm.org/) will be in London in September 2011.

Comment: Would you mind to share how you are aware of that conference?

Comment: @Dante, Sure!  I glanced through several calendars of academic computer security conferences, and clicked around a bit to determine locations for the big ones: [IEEE Cipher's calendar](http://www.ieee-security.org/Calendar/cipher-hypercalendar.html), [UCL's list of call for papers](http://www.uclouvain.be/crypto/callforpapers/forthcoming), [IACR's list](http://www.iacr.org/events/), [Cambridge's old list](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/conferences/), [some random list found via Google](http://www.conference-service.com/conferences/information-security.html).

Answer (score 2):

The [Workshop on Information Systems Security Engineering](http://gsya.esi.uclm.es/WISSE2011/) (WISSE'11) will be held in London in June 2011.  I have no prior experience with this workshop and I have no clue about whether it is a quality venue that's worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

Update - for an academic, these will be appropriate:

[**B-Sides London**](http://www.securitybsides.org.uk/) this month - some commercial, but a lot of research, both theoretical and applied

[**DC-4420**](http://dc4420.org/) regular meetings - not commercial

[**Scottish Centre of Excellence for Security and Cybercrime Symposium**](http://coe-security-and-cybercrime.net/symposium.html) - hosted by universities and trying to bridge the gap between academics and industry

Comment: I am not looking for commercial conferences. I am looking for academical ones....

Comment: @Dante - hopefully that update is useful

Comment: to be honest, I do not consider any of these to be academic conferences.  One good tip-off: they don't have a "call for papers", requesting submission of papers that will then be peer reviewed and presented at the conference.

Comment: @DW - ahhh, hadn't realised. The CoE is very academic though I don't think papers get peer reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Cyber Forensics Conference](http://www.cyberforensics.org.uk/), hosted by the University of Strathclyde scheduled for June in Glasgow

Comment: have you got links for the Ruby conf and the Bletchley one, or are they too commercial?

Comment: Would you mind to share how you are aware of that conference?

Comment: @RoryAlsop, yeah I guess they're a bit commercial for this one...

Comment: @DanteJiang I'm on the conference committee :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Security Protocols Workshop](http://spw.stca.herts.ac.uk/) tends to be held in Cambridge, UK each year.

Comment: Actually, this is the only conference occurred to me when I pressed _post your question_. But this conference is _by invitation_ as far as I am concerned.